# Java formating Float to String with precision in two numbers

Tags: java, precision

I want to convert Float into String, but I've got a problem with precision

I want to see something like `5.50` in String format.

If I use

```
String price = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(ClientOrder.TOTAL_PRICE);
totalPriceTV.setText("" + price + " " + OptionsApp.CURRENCY);
```

I will get price looking like an integer, or like `5.5`

`ClientOrder.TOTAL_PRICE` is a float number

So how to get String with 2 numbers after point?

Comment: From the javadoc: 0  Number  Yes  Digit
#  Number  Yes  Digit, zero shows as absent

Comment: Try `"#.00"` instead of `"#.##"`

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this too:

```
 String price =  String.format("%.2f", ClientOrder.TOTAL_PRICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right pattern is `"#.00"`.

```
String price = new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(ClientOrder.TOTAL_PRICE);
totalPriceTV.setText("" + price + " " + OptionsApp.CURRENCY);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) with [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)).

```
String totalPrice = "5.50158941";
String price = totalPrice.substring(0, totalPrice.indexOf(".") + 3);
```